# Prevent a repeatedly running console program from taking focus

Tags: windows, script, focus, popups

I'm running windows 7. Every 10 seconds, a script will run that will send a popup command line box and close at the end of the script.

In the meantime, when I'm using other applications, I am continuously interrupted by the poppups, which seizes focus away from my current application.

Is it possible to disable the focus of the popup command line boxes so that they will still appear but stay in the background ?

Comment: Is this your script?

Comment: sounds like a serverfault question.

Comment: If there's no good reason for those to be popping up (like Kylotan said, is it your script?  Or are you on a corporate network?), then you may have a virus.

Comment: I've had this before working on corporate machines - very annoying. Shame Windows doesn't do stuff nicely in the background like a *NIX box with cron would..

Answer (score 2):

First, **is this your script**?

If so:

- Consider running the program with hstart. It hides the console Window, preventing anybody from seeing it. Note that its best to use some kind of log file since errors won't show up either.

If not:

- Check your scheduled tasks and see if there is anything that runs very frequently and delete it. Next, do a virus scan. See if you can spot the process in task manager or System Explorer.

Comment: Absolutely agree. No script (especially not one running that frequently) should be running in a console window for the interactive user.